# Linux Debian doesn't detect HDD (booting from USB flash drive)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, debian, hardware-detection

I'm trying to install Debian on my **HDD** booting from **USB flash drive** but when I reach step called *Disk partitioning* I can see only my flash drive (`/dev/sda` automatically mounted as `/cdrom`). 
When I switch to console (*ALT+F2*) and list `/dev`, there is no `/dev/sdb`.

`mount` result:

```
~ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
none on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/sda1 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

`fdisk -l` shows only flash disk `/dev/sda`.

How can I fix it?

---

***ps 1.*** I'm not able to install Debian from CD/DVD because of [this problem](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=82104&p=444346).
***ps 2.*** My HDD is **Seagate ST1000DM003-9YN162**.
***ps 3.*** Yesterday I installed *Windows 7* on this HDD, so it's not hardware nor connection problem.

Comment: What SATA/RAID controller are you connecting the HDD to? Maybe the required drivers are in the non-free repositories.

Comment: I have **GIGABYTE Z77-D3H** motherboard ([motherboard's specification](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4140#sp)).